# Android XMPPTCPConnection: Machine is not on the network

Tags: android, xmpp, socketexception

While on Wifi, XMPPTCPConnection in our Android app is occasionally throwing "SocketException: Machine is not on the network" even though the phone does have net connection. When users turns off Wifi and turns it on again, the app is able to connect instantly.
When this exception occurs, the XMPPTCPConnection object is disconnected and set to NULL and created afresh before attempting reconnection. Yet it does not help. Below is the code snippet.

```
  try {
      if (null != connection)
      connection.disconnect();
  } catch (Exception e) {
  }

  connection = null;
  XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration connConfig = createConfiguration();
  if (null != connConfig)
  {
      connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(connConfig);
      try {
          connection.connect();
      } catch (StackOverflowError e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (XMPPException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
```

Please let me know how to fix this issue. Appreciate your help.

This is the stack trace.

org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$ConnectionException: The following addresses failed: '.com:5223' failed because java.net.SocketException: Machine is not on the network
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectUsingConfiguration(XMPPTCPConnection.java:596)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectInternal(XMPPTCPConnection.java:830)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.connect(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:360)
    at com.sarkms.cclib.XMPPConnLib.connectToChatServer(XMPPConnLib.java:184)
    at com.sarkms.cclib.XMPPConnHelper.connectToChatServer(XMPPConnHelper.java:331)
    at com.sarkms.cclib.XMPPConnHelper.LoginToChatServer(XMPPConnHelper.java:383)
    at com.sarkms.cclib.ConnChkRun.runConnectionCheck(ConnChkRun.java:83)
    at com.sarkms.cclib.ops.Connection.runConnection(Connection.java:142)
    at com.sarkms.cclib.MessageService$1.run(MessageService.java:39)

Comment: Please always include the full stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: Sure. I added it now.